# Combining two functions for working with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays of objects.

```
const details = [
    {
        ciphertext: 1234,
        buyer: {
            op_timezone: 7689,
            op_city: 'Name1',
        },
        assignment_info: { 
            info: {
                end_data: 1456,
                start_date: 2389,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        ciphertext: 5678,
        buyer: {
            op_timezone: 4568,
            op_city: 'Name2',
        },
        assignment_info: { 
            info: {
                end_data: 3467,
                start_date: 8753,
            }
        }
    },
];

const jobIds = [
    {
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
    },
];
```

I need to combine two arrays and take the assignment_info.info and buyer fields from each object.

```
function getDetailsBuyersWithJobIds(jobIds, details) {
    return jobIds.map((item, index) => ({
        ...item,
        ...details[index].buyer,
    }));
};

function getDetailsAssignmentInfosWithJobIds(jobIds, details) {
    return jobIds.map((item, index) => ({
        ...item,
        ...details[index].assignment_info.info,
    }));
};
```

The question is, how can two functions be combined into one?

That there would be no duplicate function, since they perform the same thing.

Comment: Can you just add `...details[index].assignment_info.info,` as the 3rd line of the object in the first function?

Comment: you can pass third argument stating you want 'getDetailsBuyersWithJobIds' or 'getDetailsAssignmentInfosWithJobIds' and just do condition there

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can, but the problem is that at the moment I'm taking two fields from the object, there will be more in the future

Comment: I guess you could pass `getDetailsAssignmentInfosWithJobIds` the callback used with `.map` (though that also makes `getDetailsAssignmentInfosWithJobIds` itself nearly useless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a generic mapping function and pass it a getter function that will be able to fetch the proper data, not sure it will help the global readibility though.

What do you think about that?

```js
const genericMapper = (getter) => (item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    ...getter(details[index]),
});

function getDetailsBuyersWithJobIds(jobIds, details) {
    return jobIds.map(genericMapper(it => it.buyer));
};

function getDetailsAssignmentInfosWithJobIds(jobIds, details) {
    return jobIds.map(genericMapper(it => it.assignment_info.info));
};

const details = [
    {
        ciphertext: 1234,
        buyer: {
            op_timezone: 7689,
            op_city: 'Name1',
        },
        assignment_info: { 
            info: {
                end_data: 1456,
                start_date: 2389,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        ciphertext: 5678,
        buyer: {
            op_timezone: 4568,
            op_city: 'Name2',
        },
        assignment_info: { 
            info: {
                end_data: 3467,
                start_date: 8753,
            }
        }
    },
];

const jobIds = [
    {
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
    },
];

console.log(getDetailsBuyersWithJobIds(jobIds, details));
console.log(getDetailsAssignmentInfosWithJobIds(jobIds, details));
```

Comment: I think this is better than rewriting a function

Answer (score 1):

You can add values on return object based on condition something like this

```js
const details = [{ciphertext: 1234,buyer: {op_timezone: 7689,op_city: 'Name1',},assignment_info: {info: {end_data: 1456,start_date: 2389,}}},{ciphertext: 5678,buyer: {op_timezone: 4568,op_city: 'Name2',},assignment_info: {info: {end_data: 3467,start_date: 8753,}}},];

const jobIds = [{id: 1,},{id: 2,},];

function getDetails(jobIds, details, props = {
  getBuyer: true
}) {
  return jobIds.map((item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    ...(props.getBuyer && { ...details[index].buyer
    }),
    ...(props.getAssignment && { ...details[index].assignment_info.info
    })
  }));
};


console.log(getDetails([1], details, {
  getBuyer: true
}))
console.log(getDetails([1], details, {
  getAssignment: true
}))
```

Here `props = { getBuyer: true}` used to set a default value.